# How to properly store chats between two users

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, sockets, chat

I am currently working on a private chat between two users using NodeJS, AngularJS, MySQL and Socket.IO. I want to somehow save the chats so that you don't only see the new chat you are writing that gets transmitted via Socket.IO but also the messages you have written before your current sessions.

How do I properly store these previous chats on my server?

Comment: ...by creating records in a database table?  Where are you currently stuck?  Do you need help with table design, or something else?  Also, no need to tag with Angular and Node if this is really just a database question.

Comment: This is a very broad subject and the definition of "properly" is very vague. Have you tried something or are you completely in the beginning?

Comment: I thought about just creating a table "messages" and just INSERTing every message but I thought that if you have a lot of messages it will get slow very fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is :

```
Table messages:
message_id    PRIMARY KEY
sender_id     FOREIGN KEY
recipient_id  FOREIGN KEY
Index on (sender_id, recipient_id, message_id)
Index on (recipient_id, sender_id, message_id)
```

However, this structure has a problem: there is no easy way to efficiently sort the last N messages by "id DESC" because you'll have something in your WHERE like "WHERE sender_id=... OR recipient_id=..." and this will make the last two indexes (which are intended for fast sorting) kinda useless.

A smarter structure is thus:

```
Table chatrooms:
chatroom_id PRIMARY KEY

Table chatrooms_users
chatroom_id FOREIGN KEY
user_id FOREIGN KEY
```

Now, when two users (or more) want to start chatting together, you either create or reuse a chatroom from said table, and insert the relevant lines into chatroom_users to link the chatroom to its active members. This should be updated as users join/leave the chatroom.

If conversations only involve two users (and never more than two) then you can use a simpler structure:

```
Table conversations
conversation_id PK
first_user_id   FOREIGN KEY
second_user_id  FOREIGN KEY
```

Anyway. The whole idea is to give a unique identifier to a thread of conversations between our two users, or to a chatroom. Then, the messages table becomes a lot simpler:

```
Table messages:
message_id PK
chatroom_id (or conversation_id) FK
sender_id FK
Index on (chatroom_id, message_id)
```

In this case, note that the last index optimizes this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatroom_id=constant ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Thus, when the user opens the chat window with another user, you can find the conversation_id (or chatroom_id) easily, with an index lookup, and list the last messages quickly, also using an index lookup, and without any sort.

Old messages should be pruned and moved to an archive table, to keep the messages table small and cachable in RAM.